# Second Partials test to classify a critical point

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Look at the function.

$h(u, v)  =  u^3 + 12uv − 6v^2$

(i) Find the critical points of h.

(ii)    For each critical point in (a), find the value of D(a, b) from the Second Partials test that is used to classify the critical point.

For i) I got the answer (0, 0), (-2, 2) by using the equations

$h_u=-6u^2+12v=0$
and 
$h_v=12u-6v=0$

How do I find the value of D(a,b) for ii)?

Comment: Page 2: http://www.math.ou.edu/~abhand/spring10/homework/2443notes2.pdf or Page 10: http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~groves/teaching/2011-12/165/11-21-11.pdf

Comment: Unless you wrote the formula for $h$ incorrectly (sometimes it is hard to distinguish between $u$ and $v$) both your first partials are incorrect.